# Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax Impossible to install

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, package, razor-pages

I am very simply just trying to use the `Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax` library to post ajax razor forms, but for some reason I can't get the package to install properly.

I tried installing it from the Nuget Package Manager, and I can see it in my dependancies:

[image]

But there is not folder for it under `lib`

So next, I tried right-clicking the project and managing bower package, and can now see in `bower.json`:

```
"Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax": "^3.2.3"
```

However, the library is still not present in `libs`, and when I try posting my ajax form (which i copied from [here](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/form-post)) the form is posted normally nad not 'ajax'-lly (i.e. I am redirected to the page rather than the data just posting asynchronously).

**Form**

```
<form  method="post" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-complete="complete" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="input-group">
        <label class="input-group-btn">
            <span class="btn btn-default">
                Browse&hellip; <input asp-for="Uploads" type="file" style="display: none;" accept=".xls,.xlsx,.csv" multiple>
            </span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
    </div>

    <a asp-page="Create" class="btn btn-default pull-right">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
    </a>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-up"></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

I can see that the folder exists here

```
...\bower_components\Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax
```

But that is the wrong place, and I'd rather have the package manager put it in the right place than move it manually.

Why is this happening to me? Is this normal?

Comment: you could use `LibMan` to install client dependencies: `libman install -p unpkg jquery-ajax-unobtrusive`

Answer (score 1):

You use a `.bowerrc` file to instruct Bower where to install packages: https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client-side/bower.html

The ASP.NET Core 2.1 templates do not include this file since [Bower has been deprecated](https://bower.io/blog/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but do you know why the nuget manager would also not be working? Perhaps a similar reason?

Comment: Yes - Nuget isn't great for client side stuff. You could try using LibMan as suggested by @itminus: https://dzone.com/articles/installing-client-side-libraries-in-aspnet-core - except last time I checked, Unobtrusive AJAX wasn't available on the CDNs that LibMan accesses.

Comment: @MikeBrind We can specify the provider by  `-p unpkg` : "unpkg is a fast, global content delivery network for everything on npm "